# How to slide out fragment to half of screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, slide

slide out a fragment from bottom only to a half of screen using button click.

[slide out example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skntx.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this for your activity's layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:onClick="openFragment"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your activity:

```
public void openFragment(View v) {
    Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    fragment.setEnterTransition(android.R.transition.slide_bottom);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
}
```

**NOTE:**

Works only for Api >= 21.

You will have to use `FragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations()` if you want t support older versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class `ObjectAnimator` for creating animations for your views. Using method `ofFloat` with property `translationY` you can reach the effect you want. You need API >= 11.